# Move forward with netrw in .vimrc

Tags: vim, netrw

I try to make Vim with NerdTree and Terminal.
For the terminal I use `set splitbelow` and then `:term ++rows=8`.
The problem is in .vimrc file. There I have `let g:netrw_browse_split=4`, which will open the file in the last tab I was aka the Linux terminal window. I want to move forward instead of backwards. How can I do this? [This image shows my Vim in it's current state.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhH43.png)

Comment: You would probably have to set your NerdTree to the right of your main window

Comment: I've found the solution. I can type instead of` `let g:netrw_browsesplit=`, `let g:netrw_chgwin=` and specify the window.